# Can I purchase app use Direct Carrier Billing method that its SIM card in other phone?

Tags: google-play-store

Currently there is only 1 mobile operator that its balance can be directly deducted if I purchase app in Play Store.

Unfortunately, my Android phone doesn't use that supported mobile operator and I use that mobile operator in non-Android phone.

Can I purchase app from Play Store using Direct Carrier Billing method that charge that mobile operator in my other device? I can't see the option when purchasing app in Play Store, although I have put that supported mobile operator phone number in my Google Wallet.